# ¿Cómo compruebas que los campos existen cuando intentas extraerlos en un json?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, json

Tengo un archivo JSON y me gustaria extraer pocos datos para crear un archivo csv como el siguiente:

```
Serial Number,Province,Name of candidate,Address of the contestant,Symbol Alloted,Party Affiliation,Constituency Number (ID),Constituency Name
,Chaouia - Ouardigha,,,,PI,,Ahlaf
,Chaouia - Ouardigha,,,,PJD,,Ahlaf
,Chaouia - Ouardigha,,,,PAM,,Ahlaf
...
```

Es decir, para cada circunscripción, los partidos que están allí y la provincia en cada columna.

Aqui esta el archivo JSON relacionado:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "fd597jf1799.1",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                -7.27163887,
                33.24041367
              ],
              [
                -7.27163887,
                33.24041367
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "geometry_name": "geom",
      "properties": {
        "id_0": 152,
        "iso": "MAR",
        "name_0": "Morocco",
        "id_1": 1,
        "name_1": "Chaouia - Ouardigha",
        "id_2": 1,
        "name_2": "Ben Slimane",
        "id_3": 1,
        "name_3": "Ben Slimane",
        "id_4": 1,
        "name_4": "Ahlaf",
        "varname_4": null,
        "ccn_4": 0,
        "cca_4": null,
        "type_4": "Commune Rural",
        "engtype_4": "Rural Commune",
        "bbox": [
          -7.27286911,
          33.22112656,
          -6.93353081,
          33.38970184
        ],
        "swing_count": 1,
        "polling_station_count": 15,
        "turnout": 0.4780299144225693,
        "results": {
          "PI": 187,
          "PJD": 88,
          "PAM": 59,
          "USFP": 1530,
          "APFGD": 2,
          "PPS": 15,
          "RNI": 708,
          "MP": 56,
          "UC": 3,
          "FFD": 0,
          "MDS": 0,
          "AAR": 0,
          "P Neo-Democrates": 8,
          "PEDD": 0,
          "PRD": 2,
          "PRV": 0,
          "PDI": 0,
          "PGVM": 0,
          "PALAMAL": 0,
          "PCS": 0,
          "PUD": 0,
          "PDN": 1,
          "PLJS": 0,
          "PSD": 0,
          "P Annahda": 0,
          "PA": 0,
          "UMD": 0,
          "USAPMD": 10
        },
        "voter_file": {
          "nbre_sieges": 3,
          "nbre_inscrits": 5953,
          "nbre_votants": 2997,
          "nbre_nuls": 328,
          "nbre_exprimees": 2669
        },
        "swing_ratio": 0.06666666666666667
      }
    },
    {"type": "Feature", 
    "id": "fd597jf1799.5", 
    "geometry": {
      "type": "MultiPolygon", 
      "coordinates": [[[[-7.10879707, 33.63715363], [-7.10618496, 33.6385231]]]]}, 
      "geometry_name": "geom", 
      "properties": {
        "id_0": 152, 
        "iso": "MAR", 
        "name_0": "Morocco", 
        "id_1": 1, 
        "name_1": "Chaouia - Ouardigha", 
        "id_2": 1, 
        "name_2": "Ben Slimane", 
        "id_3": 1, 
        "name_3": "Ben Slimane", 
        "id_4": 5, 
        "name_4": "Moualine El Ghaba", 
        "varname_4": None, 
        "ccn_4": 0, 
        "cca_4": None, 
        "type_4": "Commune Rural", 
        "engtype_4": "Rural Commune", 
        "bbox": [-7.25548506, 33.53932571, -7.01937389, 33.7419014],
        "swing_ratio": 0.0
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Es por decir me gustaria, para cada candidates en `results`, crear:

```
Serial Number,Province,Name of candidate,Address of the contestant,Symbol Alloted,Party Affiliation,Constituency Number (ID),Constituency Name
,{{name_1}},,,,{{results}}[i],,{{name_4}}
...
```

Como pueden ver, algunos campos de resultados pueden no existir en una circunscripción determinada. Así que ya estoy intentando hacer pruebas cuando están allí.

```
>>> for i in range(0,len(dct['features'])):
...     if(dct['features'][i]['properties']['results']):
...         for key in dct['features'][i]['properties']['results'].keys():
...             print(key)
```

Pero me da:

```
...
USAPMD
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
KeyError: 'results'
```

Estoy abierto a respuestas en javascript tambien

Comment: Pero y que paso con monica :c?, le hicieron una revolucion :v, xd ok no.

Comment: @Riven Hasta la revolucion siempre!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Uso de `dict.get` y su valor de retorno por defecto

Una forma de evitar éstos problemas es usar `dict.get` y su valor de retorno por defecto. Si asignas un diccionario vacío como valor por defecto puedes encadenar llamadas sin miedo a un `KeyError`:

```
for feature in dct['features']:
    for key in feature.get("properties", {}).get("results", {}):
        print(key)
```

---

### `dict.get` y condicionales

La otra forma usando también `dict.get` es encadenar condicionales:

**`Python >= 3.8`**

```
for feature in dct['features']:
    if (properties:= feature.get("properties")) is not None:
        if (results:= properties.get("results")) is not None:
            for key in results:
                print(key)
```

---

```
for feature in dct['features']:
    properties = feature.get("properties")
    if properties is not None:
        results = properties.get("results")
        if results is not None:
            for key in results:
                print(key)
```

Obviamente si encadenamos muchas claves todo se vuelve poco legible y tedioso, podemos crear una función que se encargue de iterar:

```
def get_chained(dic, *keys, default=None):
    for key in keys:
        value = dic.get(key)
        if value is None:
            return default
        dic = value
    return value

for feature in dct['features']:
    for key in get_chained(feature, "properties", "results", default={}):
        print(key)
```

---

### Manejo de excepciones

La tercera vía sería simplemente manejar la excepción, aunque hay desarrolladores que no comulgan con dicha práctica, en Python es una practica comúnmente aceptada y usada:

```
for feature in dct['features']:
    try:
        for key in feature['properties']['results'].keys():
            print(key)
    except KeyError:
        pass
```